# Adventures with automating Ubuntu install & VirtualBox

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, encryption, keyboard-layout, preseed

I've been working on an automated install of Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS desktop under VirtualBox 6.1, using the VBoxManage utility, including the requirement for an encrypted system disk.

I've hit a couple of bumps in the road which have been an adventure to work around...

1. VirtualBox's native encryption is not implemented in VBoxManage, so OS encryption has to be used.
2. If you want an encrypted ("d-i partman-auto/method string crypto") installation, specify "--no-install-additions" to exclude installation of the VirtualBox Additions from the build; it looks like the installation (debian_postinstall.sh) interferes with the creation of the init ramdisk and it won't work.
3. If you're not bothered about wiping the VM's virtual disk before installation, then a `sed` command can be run to disable it (if you set the "erase_disks"/"erase_data" directives to false and watch the build you may well see the disk being cleared):

   ```
   d-i partman/early_command string sed -i 's:-f $id/skip_erase:-d $id:g' /lib/partman/lib/crypto-base.sh
   ```
4. All of the examples of keyboard handling show it being set to "us"... The reason is that only "us" works and if you choose any other layout you get "us" anyway! I found this fix for it:

   ```
   enter code d-i preseed/late_command_string \
   in-target /bin/sed -i 's/XKBLAYOUT=.*/XKBLAYOUT="gb,us"/' 
   /etc/default/keyboard ;\
   in-target /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive keyboard- 
   configurationhere
   ```
5. (This is a good one!) In specifying the "recipe" for a disk layout (eg. sda1=boot, sda2=extended, sda5=LVM on the extended partition), pay special attention to the apparent typo which is a space between "in_vg" and the following "{" - that space is needed and without it the build will fail, saying there aren't any physical disks!

   ```
       enter cd-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string ubuntu-vg
   d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-disk
   d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string root-disk ::  \
       1024 1024 1024 ext4                         \
           $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
           method{ format } format{ }              \
           use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
           mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
           .                                       \
       10240 10240 -1 ext4                         \
           $lvmok{ }                               \
           in_vg { ubuntu-vg } lv_name{ lv_root }   \
           method{ format } format{ }              \
           use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
           mountpoint{ / }                         \
           .                                       \
       1024 1024 100% linux-swap                   \
           $lvmok{ }                               \
           in_vg { ubuntu-vg } lv_name{ swap_1 }    \
           method{ swap } format{ }                \
           .
   ```
6. If you don't specify a root password then the OS is installed with your named user granted Sudo rights. If you do specify a root passwd then the named user does NOT get Sudo.

There are several hours of my life I've spend discovering the above which I won't get back; hopefully these few comments will allow you to spend that time more fruitfully.

Has anybody else got anything to add?

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Questions and answers should be posted separately.

Comment: I think that if you ask the question and then post the answer, it is easier for people with the same question, to google and find the answer. Your question might be:  How to Automate Ubuntu Install & VirtualBox with Encryption. Then post this as an answer below. Looks like valuable info to me, good of you to pass it along.

Comment: Thanks - I converted it to a question... :-)